# What are the pull timings in 6.88?

Tags: dota-2

With the map changed up, the pull timings changed. What are the timings on the pulls now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Stack Timings***

**Radiant**

- Radiant large camp near T2 mid - :55-:56
- Radiant medium camp near T1 mid - :55
- Radiant medium camp near bot rune - :54-:55
- Radiant small camp - :55
- Radiant large camp near bot lane - :53
- Radiant large camp near secret shop - :53-:54
- Radiant Ancients - :53-:54

**Dire**

- Dire large camp near top lane - :53-:54
- Dire small camp - :54-:55
- Dire medium camp near top rune - :54
- Dire medium camp near T2 Top - :54-:55
- Dire large camp near mid T2 - :53-:54
- Dire large camp near secret shop - :55 (pull towards mid lane) *most tricky stack
- Dire ancients - :53-:54

***Pull into lane Timings***

- :22-:24 and :53-:55 for both Radiant and Dire Safelane large camps
- :14-:16 and :44-:46 for both Radiant and Dire Safelane small camps

If you pull the large camp into lane at :53 it is a stack as well as a pull.

Do try for yourself in lobby once or download the neutral spawn boxes arcade game and practice stacking to get better at it. Good luck :)

Comment: Are these stack timings or pull into lane timings?

Comment: These are Stack Timings.

Comment: I'm looking for the pull timings.

Comment: @Reactormonk I have added the pull timings after the stack timings. Cheers.